# How do you get a widget's children in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, widget, keypress, qtestlib

I'm simulating keyPresses to an application through Qt's KeyPress function. All the KeyPresses work fine. However when I pass a `QT::Key_Enter` which is supposed to press the OK button of the currently active window, or `QT::Key_Cancel` for the cancel button, it does nothing.

I'm thinking maybe, because these buttons don't have the focus, and the parent window itself has it. How do you get the children of a window? or rather find the OK or Cancel button on it so you could set it as the activeWindow and then pass KeyPresses successfully?

I have:

```
QWidget *pWin = QApplication::activeWindow;
QObjectList *pList = pWin->children();
//how do you iterate through the list and find the OK or Cancel button?
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the [`findChild()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qobject.html#findChild) function with the object name to get a specific child.

You can also use `findChildren()` to get all the children that have the same name and then iterate through the list using `foreach()` or [`QListIterator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qlistiterator.html).

To get a button you can try:

```
QPushButton* button = pWin->findChild<QPushButton*>("Button name");
```

Comment: how do I use the QListIterator?

Comment: It is explained in the documentation: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlistiterator.html#details

Comment: yeah, I've read that. But I think it's different when you get a list of QWidget's children...

Comment: Why? It's the same for all classes. You only have to put your own code in the while loop

Comment: yeah, I know... what I mean is I might be missing something. Can you tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: QWidget *pWin = QApplication::activeWindow();
    QList<QPushButton *> pButtons = pWin.findChildren<QPushButton *>();
    QListIterator<QPushButton> i(pButtons);

Comment: 1. pWin can be NULL if there is no active Window. 2. If your list is a QList<QPushButton*> your iterator must be QListIterator<QPushButton*>

Comment: No need to use the iterator type explicitly:
auto list = pWin.findChildren<QPushButton*>();
for(QPushButton* btn : list)
    btn->foo();

Answer (score 2):

You might want to put a custom [event filter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/eventsandfilters.html) on your widget to capture the key event and see what really happens to it.