# Accessing multiple widgets

Tags: python, qt, widget, qlineedit

I have made a GUI using Qt Designer, I have like 20 or more lineEdit widgets, I am looking for the correct way to access all of them without having to access each one...I explain with an example in pseudocode:

This is what I DON'T want:

```
lineEdit1.setText("Value = 1")
lineEdit2.setText("Value = 2")
lineEdit3.setText("Value = 3")
and so on, up to
lineEdit20.setText("Value = 20")
```

I am looking for something like THIS:

```
for i in xrange(1,21):

    lineEdit(i).setText("Value = whatever")
```

The problem is that, as far as I know, when dragging and dropping widgets, Qt Designer automatically adds a number to the end of the name...lineEdit1, lineEdit2,....so after that I do not know how to access all of them in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't have to accept the name that is automatically assigned in Qt Designer. Just set the `objectName` property to whatever is most suitable.

To iterate over groups of widgets, there are several QObject methods available.

The most powerful is [findChildren](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChildren) which can search recursively for objects/widgets based on their class:

```
for child in self.findChildren(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    child.setValue(value)
```

and also their objectName:

```
rgx = QtCore.QRegExp('lineEdit[0-9]+')
for child in self.findChildren(QtGui.QLineEdit, rgx):
    child.setValue(value)
```

But a simpler technique would be to use Qt Designer to put all the widgets inside a container widget (such as a QWidget, QFrame, QGroupBox, etc), and then use the non-recursive [children](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#children) method to loop over them:

```
for index, child in enumerate(self.groupBox.children()):
    child.setValue(value[index])
```

You might also want to consider using a [QFormLayout](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qformlayout.html), which provides a more structured way of doing things. This is available in Qt Designer: just drag and drop a `Form Layout` onto your main form and then use `Add form layout row` from the right-click menu to add widgets to it.

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know those thing findChildren etc, sounds like it is what I am looking for. Thanks again for your answer, I will try with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the QT designer, I guess your best solution is to simply add widgets  to a list.
I know this is sub-optimal, but this way you will only have to do it once.

```
lineEditL = []
lineEditL.append(lineEdit1)
lineEditL.append(lineEdit2)
```

An other solution is to simply iterate the children. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311352/how-do-you-get-a-widgets-children-in-qt), no reason to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
QWidget *pWin = QApplication::activeWindow();
for( int i=1; i<=21; i++ ) {
    QString strName ="LineEdit"+QString::number(i);
    QLineEdit *le = pWin->findChild<QLineEdit *>(strName);
    if( le ) le->setText("Value = "+Qstring::number(i) );
}
```