# How to write Qt test for a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have read the 5 tutorial from [QT-test website](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtest-tutorial.html). But they are not what I want.
I want to build a project and its unit test part is detached from the main program.

For example:
In main program has a push-botton on widgets and if it was clicked then a Qlabel will show a number.
If I run the test programm, It would mock MouseClicked Event on that button, then verify if the value which shows up on Qlabel is our expectations.

My question is how can I get my test program linked to the main program so that I can access its members? Besides that I want to build the project using CMake, how should I write the CMakeLists for the test project?

```
---root 
|---test
  |----CmakeLists.txt
  |----test.cpp
  |----test.h
|---build
|----main.cpp // only int main function 
|----QMainwindows.cpp 
|----QMainwindows.h
|----QMainwindows.ui
|----CmakeLists.txt
```

And the CMakeLists.txt in root

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
project(myproject VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
QMainwindows.cpp 
QMainwindows.h
QMainwindows.ui
)
add_executable(myproject ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(myprojectPRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)
```

I am also confused how to access the members from mainwindow in our test. I mean I cant include the ui_mainwindow.h and create an UI_Mainwindow Instance

Comment: You can not link against an executable - therefore create a (static) library with all sources except main and use this then for creating your executable and your unit test.

Comment: @chehrlic thank your for your advice!  I've actually tried this by generating different functions as different libraries and then In test folder CMake using  'target link library' and it works. But I'm not sure if I'm doing this as a common practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an approach that could answer my question.

In test part I can use `findchild<T>("WidgetsName")` to get access to ui members of any class.

reference : [How do you get a widget's children in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311352/how-do-you-get-a-widgets-children-in-qt)

This may not be a universal solution and if anyone has a better idea, I would be grateful.